# remove old primary domain email addresses from exchange 2007

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2007

I have recently added a new primary domain to our company and all users have the new email and all is good. It's now time to remove the old domain email that are coming in. (At this point they are all spam as we have been using the new domain for a while.) What would the best way to make all the old domains emails go to our dedicated spam account. When I go to the users and try to delete the old email from each account, it comes right back.  Any hints on the proper solution would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the email address for the old domain gets recreated after you remove it from the mailbox, you probably need to remove the address from the e-mail address policy. If you're using the EMC, expand the Org config and go to the Hub Transport. This should list the address policies. Edit the policy that contains the old domain address so it no longer contains the old domain..  umm.., this should have been the way you added the new domain too..